# Error when converting 'String' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page with a nested Gridview where I'm trying to fill the inner grid by pulling a string value from each line of the outer grid. When I try to pass the value from the outer grid to the string variable I get the "Error when converting 'String' to 'System.IFormatProvider'" error. I'm using the following code to store the gridview cell value to the variable:

```
 Dim Svc_Name As String = grdOuterGridView.DataKeyNames(e.Row.RowIndex).ToString("THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE")
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: What is "THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DataKeysNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is already an array of string, you don't need the ToString(....) part.

```
 Dim Svc_Name As String = grdOuterGridView.DataKeyNames(e.Row.RowIndex)
```

Actually your error comes from the ToString("THIRD_PARTY_SERVICE"). The ToString() override that takes one parameter requires an object that implements `IFormatProvider` interface, but of course a string doesn't have this interface, thus the error. However, calling ToString() on a String has no effect as you can read from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tostring.aspx)

> Returns this instance of String; no actual conversion is performed.